# My installation does not load content

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.0

I am really new to this world of magento, I installed Magento 2.4 in XAMPP with the help of compposer, elastic search, I did everything to the letter, when I checked my installation I saw that it does not load content neither in the frontend nor in the backend, does not mark an error, it just does not load the content already run ----reindex, upgrade, static-content: deploy –f and flush
upgrade

But it remains the same, I would appreciate if you could help me give clues of what it could be[image]here de image without content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:140
```

**the string**

```
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

**to replace**

```
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
   return true;
}
```

After run all commmands.

**`THANKS.`**